# JavaScript reduce a filtered list

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that I want to filter before then reducing one of their properties down into an accumulator.

**Edit:** in the end what I want is one number.

I could do it in two steps like this:

```
let filteredList = list.filter( item => item.topLevel )
return filteredList.reduce( (a, i) => a + i.stock ), 0)
```

but I'm hip and 'with the ES6' so I want to do it in one line.

Help me stack overflow, how do I combine filter and reduce?

**Edit:** for the record I've tried this:

```
    product_variations.filter( pv => pv.topLevel )
            .reduce((a, fpv) => a + fpv.stock) , 0)
```

and it seems to be returning an array. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

**Edit:** I was asked to show the desired inputs and outputs:

```
[{topLevel: true, stock: 12}, {topLevel: false, stock: 5}, {topLevel: true, stock: 10}]
// returns 22
```

Comment: Probably like this 
`let filteredList = list.filter( item => item.topLevel ).reduce( (a, i) => a + i.stock ), 0)`

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, in the end what I want is a reduction of one of the properties of this sorted list

Comment: Please share the input array and expected output array

Comment: Should work fine as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misplaced closing parenthesis in your code. Removing that will fix it:

```js
const productVariations = [{
  topLevel: true,
  stock: 1
}, {
  topLevel: false,
  stock: 2
}];

const result = productVariations.filter(pv => pv.topLevel)
                                .reduce((a, fpv) => a + fpv.stock, 0);
                                
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind doing it in *one line*, chaining `filter` and `reduce` calls results in multiple iterations of your list – doing it *one iteration* is smart thing to do

```
list.reduce
  ( (acc, item) =>
      Boolean (item.topLevel)
        ? acc + item.stock
        : acc
  , 0
  )
```

---

Did you know that `filter` can be written in terms of `reduce`?

```js
const filter = (f, xs) =>
  xs.reduce
    ( (acc, x) =>
        f (x)
          ? [ ...acc, x ]
          : acc
    , []
    )

console.log (filter (x => x > 3, [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]))
// [ 4, 5 ]
```

So when you were writing `list.filter(...).reduce(...)` we can imagine this as a *sequence* of reduces. Did you know that this sequencing of reduces can be generalized? Below we introduce something called *transducers* which provide a way to sequence many reduction steps together but only touch the underlying data once - no matter how many reduction steps you add to the sequence

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const add = (x, y) =>
  x + y
    
const tfilter = f => concat =>
  (acc, x) => f (x) ? concat (acc, x) : acc
  
const tmap = f => concat =>
  (acc, x) => concat (acc, f (x)) 
  
const comp = (f, g) =>
  x => f (g (x))
  
const transduce = (...ts) => (f, init, xs) =>
  xs.reduce
    ( ts.reduce (comp, identity) (f)
    , init
    )
  
const main =
  transduce
    ( tfilter (x => x.topLevel)
    , tmap (x => x.stock)
    )
    
const data =
  [ { topLevel: true, stock: 1 }
  , { topLevel: false, stock: 10 }
  , { topLevel: true, stock: 1 }
  , { topLevel: true, stock: 1 }
  ]

console.log (main (add, 0, data))
// 3
```

If you're interested in transducers, they're useful for solving some neat problems. I've written about them more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A633183+transducers)